# How can server send JWT token to the browser

Tags: javascript, html, jwt

Below is example response to the browser.

```
        HTTP / 1.1 200 OK
            Content - Type: application / json
            Cache - Control : no - store
            Pragma : no - cache

        {
            "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
            "token_type" : "bearer",
            "expires_in" : 3600,
            "refresh_token" : "IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
            "scope" : "create"
        }
```

Which part of result HTML page, JSON object should be included? Is it HTTP header or HTTP Cookie or HTML body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JWT would be in the body of the response. There is no HTML involved! Keep in mind that what you posted in your snippet is a JSON object, not a JWT (which are in thise base64 encoded format).

Comment: Thanks for telling me that "there is no HTML involved". It is big learning for me,a new comer to Web development.

As a next step, how can my browser ( using java script)  read the JSON object from the http response and save into C:\.. 

Assume my initial HTML page is GetToken.html which takes name and password and have a submit button. Once submit button is clicked, Server will get the username and password, creates a JWT token and put the JSON object in HTTP response(I will put JSON object as you said)

Comment: I can have the JavaScript to save JSON object to C:\ in GetToken.html. But after I get HTTP response from the server, in the browser I see JSON object in same page GetToken.html. But at this point, GetToken.html has no javascript when I do a view source.

Kindly let me know if my question make any sense. Sorry I am a novice, I do not know even how to ask right questions...But my objective is to store JSON object from HTTP response to be saved in C:\

Comment: JWT are usually saved (persisted) in local storage, session storage, or cookies. The browser doesn't normally have random access to your file system, if that's what your trying to do.